# How can i create this (Ps2 Characters & Enviroment)

Tags: rendering, rigging, development

{ https://de.files.fm/u/mu93hd5qz }

Hello

I‘m wondering since days on how to make something like this.
I wanna put myself as a „ps2“ character and i‘m curious on how he did it on the video. is there a addon for this, to put oneself 1:1 in blender?
which addons would you guys recommend for the scenery, movements?

Comment: Hello, you don't need any addon, just create a character and project a photo of yourself onto its surface, then animate?

Comment: So is there a template in Blender? Or what would you recommend on creating this character?

Comment: You can find a lot of ready-made characters in some websites but not in Blender itself (or maybe with some addons). If you are familiar with modeling, model it yourself?

Comment: i will thank you! yes i‘m new to blender u maybe got a tip on how i can lay out the fotos of myself  after i created the blank transparent model?

Comment: you can use the Project from View unwrap method, it will need some corrections in Texture Painting mode though, but it's a bit too broad to be explained here  ;)

Comment: oh ty very much. u got a link to a fully explaination? :)

Comment: look for Unwrap > Project From View or maybe Texture Paint > Stencil, and choose the method you prefer